# How to avoid widows and orphans in ToC?

Tags: table-of-contents, page-breaking, widows-orphans

I want the chapter's author name being shown in the ToC. So I have modified the chapter to add the author there and use it in the page header as follows:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc} 

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} % Subsection mit Zähler (1.1) versehen

%%
% Kolumnentitel
%%
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{ \markboth{#1}{}  } % Stil der Kopfzeile zurücksetzen
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{ \markright{#1}{} } % Stil der Kopfzeile 

% Page style
\makepagestyle{mystyle}
\makeevenhead{mystyle}{\thepage}{\small\chapterauthor}{}
\makeoddhead{mystyle}{}{\slshape\leftmark}{\thepage}
\pagestyle{mystyle}

%%
% Inhaltsverzeichnis
%%
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterdotsep}{\cftdotsep}
\settocdepth{chapter}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterfont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterpagefont}{\normalfont}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\authortoctext[1]{%
{\addvspace{10pt}\nopagebreak\leftskip0em\relax
\rightskip \@tocrmarg\relax
\noindent\itshape#1\par\addvspace{-7pt}}}
\makeatother
\newcommand\authortoc[1]{%
  \gdef\chapterauthor{#1}%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\authortoctext{#1}}}

%%
% Dokumentenbeginn
%%
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents* 
\authortoc{Walter von der Vogelweide}
\chapter{Ich sass uf eynem Steine?}
\section{Und dachte Bein mit Beine}
\Blindtext\Blindtext\Blindtext\Blindtext

\authortoc{Hartman von Aue}
\chapter[Was auch immer]{So gebt nur mehr und immer mehr}
\section{Moralische Quellen der Irrationalitat}
\Blindtext\Blindtext\Blindtext\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

Everything works as expected, but I have the problem that sometimes author's name and chapter's title are split up by the page break. So that the first become an orphan and the latter a widow. How to avoid that?

Comment: Load the `needspace` package and add a line `\addtocontents{toc}{\needspace{2em}}%` before `\addtocontents{toc}{\authortoctext{#1}}}` in the definition of `\authortoc`.

Comment: @karlkoeller  See answer below.  Your fix did not actually work, though like you, I thought it would have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have thought Karl Koeller's comment would have worked, but it did not seem to.  What did work is shown below, in which `\needspace{2\baselineskip}` is added *within* the argument to `\authortoctext`, prior to `#1`.

In this MWE, I changed the `textheight` to reproduce the problem when the remedy is not implemented.

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{memoir}
\textheight=10.5cm
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{setspace}% NEED THIS PACKAGE

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} % Subsection mit Zähler (1.1) versehen

%%
% Kolumnentitel
%%
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{ \markboth{#1}{}  } % Stil der Kopfzeile zurücksetzen
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{ \markright{#1}{} } % Stil der Kopfzeile 

% Page style
\makepagestyle{mystyle}
\makeevenhead{mystyle}{\thepage}{\small\chapterauthor}{}
\makeoddhead{mystyle}{}{\slshape\leftmark}{\thepage}
\pagestyle{mystyle}

%%
% Inhaltsverzeichnis
%%
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterdotsep}{\cftdotsep}
\settocdepth{chapter}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterfont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterpagefont}{\normalfont}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\authortoctext[1]{%
{\addvspace{10pt}\nopagebreak\leftskip0em\relax
\rightskip \@tocrmarg\relax
\noindent\itshape#1\par\addvspace{-7pt}}}
\makeatother
\newcommand\authortoc[1]{\needspace{3\baselineskip}%
  \gdef\chapterauthor{#1}%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\authortoctext{%
    \needspace{2\baselineskip}%  <THIS IS THE ADDED LINE
  #1}}}

%%
% Dokumentenbeginn
%%
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents* 
\authortoc{Walter von der Vogelweide}
\chapter{Ich sass uf eynem Steine?}
\section{Und dachte Bein mit Beine}
\Blindtext\Blindtext\Blindtext\Blindtext

\authortoc{Hartman von Aue}
\chapter[Was auch immer]{So gebt nur mehr und immer mehr}
\section{Moralische Quellen der Irrationalitat}
\Blindtext\Blindtext\Blindtext\Blindtext

\authortoc{Hartman von Aue}
\chapter[Was auch immer]{So gebt nur mehr und immer mehr}
\section{Moralische Quellen der Irrationalitat}
\Blindtext\Blindtext\Blindtext\Blindtext

\authortoc{Hartman von Aue}
\chapter[Was auch immer]{So gebt nur mehr und immer mehr}
\section{Moralische Quellen der Irrationalitat}
\Blindtext\Blindtext\Blindtext\Blindtext

\authortoc{Hartman von Aue}
\chapter[Was auch immer]{So gebt nur mehr und immer mehr}
\section{Moralische Quellen der Irrationalitat}
\Blindtext\Blindtext\Blindtext\Blindtext

\authortoc{Hartman von Aue}
\chapter[Was auch immer]{So gebt nur mehr und immer mehr}
\section{Moralische Quellen der Irrationalitat}
\Blindtext\Blindtext\Blindtext\Blindtext

\authortoc{Hartman von Aue}
\chapter[Was auch immer]{So gebt nur mehr und immer mehr}
\section{Moralische Quellen der Irrationalitat}
\Blindtext\Blindtext\Blindtext\Blindtext

\authortoc{Hartman von Aue}
\chapter[Was auch immer]{So gebt nur mehr und immer mehr}
\section{Moralische Quellen der Irrationalitat}
\Blindtext\Blindtext\Blindtext\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works pretty well, but can anybody tell me, why the author's name get's an indent and how to avoid that? Sorry for the stupid question, I am a beginner.

Comment: @user5950 The definition of `\authortoctext` needs to have some `\leftskip` in order to align with the chapter number rather than the chapter name.  For example, here I shift 1.7em to the left:  `\DeclareRobustCommand\authortoctext[1]{%
{\addvspace{10pt}\nopagebreak\leftskip-1.7em\relax
\rightskip \@tocrmarg\relax
\noindent\itshape#1\par\addvspace{-7pt}}}`