# How to use memoir environment to set a motto for a chapter?

Tags: epigraphs, poetry

I would like to set a motto after the chapter title. While the title is set left-aligned the motto should be set left-aligned too, but the longest line of the motto should be aligned to the right outer border of the page:

```
The Title is Great
That is the subtitle if there is one

The Authors name

                         There was a young man of Quebec
                         Who was frozen in snow to his neck.
                         When asked: ‘Are you friz?’
                         He replied: ‘Yes, I is,
                         But we don’t call this cold in Quebec. 

1. Maybe the section title
And last but not least the text of the essay and what else I do
not know...
```

This is a working example, but what I need to know is, how to set the whole 'block' with the poetry to the right border (that the longest verse hits it)?

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\newcommand{\chapterauthor}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\authortoctext[1]{%
{\addvspace{10pt}\nopagebreak\setlength{\parindent}{0em}\relax
\rightskip \@tocrmarg\relax
\itshape#1\par\addvspace{-7pt}}}
\makeatother
\newcommand\authortoc[1]{\needspace{3\baselineskip}%
  \gdef\chapterauthor{#1}%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\authortoctext{%
    \needspace{2\baselineskip}%   Vgl. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134016
#1}}}
\renewcommand{\afterchaptertitle}{%

\vskip\onelineskip\begin{large}\normalfont\textit{\Large\chapterauthor}\end{large}
\vspace{4ex}
\vskip\onelineskip}

\newcommand\Chapter[3][]{
  \chapter[%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax #2%
  \else #1\fi. #3]{#2\\[2ex]\Large\Large#3}
  \chaptermark]{\markboth{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax  #2%
  \else  #1\fi }{}%  
}}


\begin{document}
\authortoc{The Author}
\chapter[]{The Title of the Chapter}
\settowidth{\versewidth}{I will pour out my spirit on all people} 
\begin{verse}
In the last days, God says, \\
I will pour out my spirit on all people. \\
Your sons and daughters will prophesy, \\
\ldots \\
And everyone who calls \ldots ’’\,’
\end{verse}

\section*{The section Title}
\blindtext
```

\end{document}

Comment: Related/duplicate: [“Inspirational” quote at start of chapter](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53377/5764)

Comment: @Werner Wow, that was fast! Sorry, I did not find that one. Seems to solve my problem.