# Problems with line-break in Chapter Title using a custom Command for Chapter

Tags: sectioning, line-breaking, chapters

If you have to force a line break in a chapter title, this would be possible doing so:

```
\chapter[][A Long title that has to be broken,\\ how sad is this!]
```

But in my document I had to define my own chapter command, in order to have a chapter author and a subtitle:

```
\newcommand\Chapter[3][]{%
  % Last char of the title 
  \StrRight{#2}{1}[\lastchar]%
  % Put to \
  \chapter[#2%
    % We want a point in the ToC between title and subtitle
    \if\relax\detokenize{#3}\relax%
    \else%
      % But not if there is a ?
      \if\lastchar? %
      \else%
        % Or a !
        \if\lastchar! %
        % If not set a point        
        \else%
        . %
        \fi%
      \fi%
    \fi%
  #3]{#2\\[2ex]\Large\Large#3}
  \chaptermark]{\markboth{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax  #2%
  \else  #1\fi }{}%  
}}
```

This works as expected, but not with a line break:

```
\Chapter[A Long title]{A Long title that has to be broken,\\ how sad is this!}{Some boring subtitles}
```

With the line break I get an error:

```
! Paragraph ended before \@firstoftwo was complete.
<to be read again>
\par
l.2 ...how sad is this!}{}
I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
```

How ever, the line break works, but on the page before there appears the part after the line break on an extra page. What did I wrong?

Here is a complete working example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{xstring}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xltxtra}

\newcommand{\chapterauthor}

\renewcommand*{\cftchapterdotsep}{\cftdotsep}
\settocdepth{chapter}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterfont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterpagefont}{\normalfont}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\authortoctext[1]{%
{\addvspace{10pt}\nopagebreak\setlength{\parindent}{0em}\relax
\rightskip \@tocrmarg\relax
\itshape#1\par\addvspace{-7pt}}}
\makeatother
\newcommand\authortoc[1]{\needspace{3\baselineskip}%
  \gdef\chapterauthor{#1}%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\authortoctext{%
    \needspace{2\baselineskip}%   Vgl. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134016
#1}}}


\renewcommand{\afterchaptertitle}{%

\vskip\onelineskip\begin{large}\normalfont\textit{\Large\chapterauthor}\end{large}
\vspace{4ex}
\vskip\onelineskip}

\newcommand\testchain[1]{%
  \StrRight{#1}{1}[\lastchar]%
  \IfStrEq{\lastchar}{?}{false}{true}%
}


\newcommand\Chapter[3][]{%
  % Last char of the title 
  \StrRight{#2}{1}[\lastchar]%
  % Put to \
  \chapter[#2%
    % We want a point in the ToC between title and subtitle
    \if\relax\detokenize{#3}\relax%
    \else%
      % But not if there is a ?
      \if\lastchar? %
      \else%
        % Or a !
        \if\lastchar! %
        % If not set a point        
        \else%
        . %
        \fi%
      \fi%
    \fi%
  #3]{#2\\[2ex]\Large\Large#3}
  \chaptermark]{\markboth{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax  #2%
  \else  #1\fi }{}%  
}}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents*


   \Chapter[A Long title]{A Long title that has to be broken,\\ how sad is this!}{Some boring subtitles}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility: using

```
% settings to redefine \newline and then recover its original meaning
\let\oldnewline\newline
% redefinition: \newline is \relax
\newcommand\AnnCL{%
  \def\newline{\relax}}
% recovering the original meaning of \newline
\newcommand\RecCL{%
  \def\newline{\oldnewline}}
```

I defined two commands `\AnnCL` and `\RecCL` to redefine `\newline` as `\relax` and then to recover its original meaning. Using these commands in the proper locations in your definition of `\Chapter` allows you now to use `\newline` inside the first mandatory argument of `\Chapter`. A line break will occur in the document body, but no effect will be present in the ToC.

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\chapterauthor}

\renewcommand*{\cftchapterdotsep}{\cftdotsep}
\settocdepth{chapter}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterfont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterpagefont}{\normalfont}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\authortoctext[1]{%
{\addvspace{10pt}\nopagebreak\setlength{\parindent}{0em}\relax
\rightskip \@tocrmarg\relax
\itshape#1\par\addvspace{-7pt}}}
\makeatother
\newcommand\authortoc[1]{\needspace{3\baselineskip}%
  \gdef\chapterauthor{#1}%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\authortoctext{%
    \needspace{2\baselineskip}%   Vgl. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134016
#1}}}


\renewcommand{\afterchaptertitle}{%

\vskip\onelineskip\begin{large}\normalfont\textit{\Large\chapterauthor}\end{large}
\vspace{4ex}
\vskip\onelineskip}

\newcommand\testchain[1]{%
  \StrRight{#1}{1}[\lastchar]%
  \IfStrEq{\lastchar}{?}{false}{true}%
}

% settings to redefine \newline and then recover its original meaning
\let\oldnewline\newline
% redefinition: \newline is \relax
\newcommand\AnnCL{%
  \def\newline{\relax}}
% recovering the original meaning of \newline
\newcommand\RecCL{%
  \def\newline{\oldnewline}}

\newcommand\Chapter[3][]{\AnnCL%
  % Last char of the title 
  \StrRight{#2}{1}[\lastchar]%
  % Put to \
  %
  \chapter[#2%
    % We want a point in the ToC between title and subtitle
    \if\relax\detokenize{#3}\relax%
    \else%
      % But not if there is a ?
      \if\lastchar? %
      \else%
        % Or a !
        \if\lastchar! %
        % If not set a point        
        \else%
        .%
        \fi%
      \fi%
    \fi%
  #3]{\RecCL#2\\[2ex]\Large\Large#3}
  \chaptermark]{\markboth{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax  #2%
  \else  #1\fi }{}%  
}\RecCL}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents*

\Chapter[A Long title]{A Long title that has to be\newline broken,  how sad is this!}{Some boring subtitles}

\end{document}
```

An image of the ToC:

[image]

An image of the page containing the chapter heading:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that `\StrRight` tries full expansion of the argument and `\\` doesn't survive it.

If you want the line break also in the table of contents, then saying

```
\newcommand\Chapter[3][]{%
  % Last char of the title
  \saveexpandmode\noexpandarg
  \StrRight{#2}{1}[\lastchar]%
  \restoreexpandmode
  % Put to \
  \chapter[#2%
  <...the rest is the same...>
```

solves your problem. Otherwise, just define `\?` to be a line break in the text and locally define it to be a no op in the table of contents:

```
\protected\def\?{\\}
```

and say

```
\begingroup\let\?\relax
\tableofcontents*
\endgroup

\Chapter[A Long title]
  {A Long title that has to be broken,\? how sad is this!}
  {Some boring subtitles}
```

I would keep the `\noexpandarg` when doing `\StrRight` anyway.